# Passenger not showing my application on restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger

I configured and deployed an app using RoR Passanger NGINX and everything worked fine. (ubuntu 16.04 on digitalocean)
Tried to switch domain name to a different domain and created a new ssl certificate for it. (previous domain also used ssl)

Changed the domain name from the old domain to the new one in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

When running:  passenger-config restart-app
I get :
"Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications."

And my new domain is not picked yet up.

Restarting passenger previously showed my app.

What am I doing wrong or what did I miss since passenger is not seeing my app anymore?